# How do I exchange an Auth Code for a Token?

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, postman

I am working on configuring my OAUTH2 server to support the authorization_code flow, but I am hitting a wall trying to exchange an access code for an access_token.  Every time I test the call I am getting back an invalid_grant error.

Here is how I understand the flow to work:

1. The client places a GET request to the oauth server authorize endpoint.
2. The oauth server validates the client and callback url
3. The oauth server sends the auth code in a querystring to the callbackurl.
4. The client (callbackurl) issues a POST request to the token endpoint with a grant_type of authorization_code with the code in the body of the request.
5. The OAuth server returns the client a token that may be used for requests.

The last method to fire in my code is the AuthenticationTokenProvider.Receive method, but I am getting an invalid_grant error instead of having a token generate.  I presume this method should trigger another call someplace, and perhaps I am just missing something in my configuration.

Here is how I have configured OAuth in my environment:

```
            var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = allowInsecureHttp,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/authorize"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(HlGlobals.Kernel),
                AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(_baseUrl, HlGlobals.Kernel),
                AuthorizationCodeProvider = new SimpleAuthenticationTokenProvider()
            };


            // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
```

I am able to obtain an authorization code that gets sent to the callback url without issue.

Inside of postman I am using https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback as my callback url.  However, I have also tried placing the subsequent request to my token endpoint via a postman POST request as well.  Both approaches produce the same result.

The second call, the POST call to the oauth server that includes the code in the body triggers the following events before returning a 400:

1. OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider - ValidateClientAuthentication
2. AuthenticationTokenProvider - Receive

In the receive method I verify that the code is valid before calling context.DeserializeTicket(value).

I understand the purpose of the ReceiveCode method to be removing the one time use code from the data store in addition to kicking off the token creation process.... but I am uncertain.

Any thoughts on what I am missing, and how I can implement the server code to exchange an auth code for an auth token using the authorization_code grant_type?

I am happy to supply any additional information upon request.  Thanks!